# Data going into SQLite3 Table letter by letter not word by word

Tags: python, sqlite, beautifulsoup

I am trying to put a set of elements scraped from the web into an SQLite3 table.

```
(Prior,)(Rat the Cafe,)(Ampersand Coffee and Food,)(Umberto Espresso Bar,)(Brother Alec,)(Short Round,)(Jerry Joy,)(The Old Milk Bar,)(Little Henri,)(Northern Soul,)
```

I have figured out how make the elements scraped go into the database table but they are going in as individual letters rather than whole words (see image below).

Here is the code:

```
try:
    url = 'https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-thornbury' #go to the website
    response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)

    soup_cafe_names = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    type(soup_cafe_names)

    cafeNames = soup_cafe_names.findAll('h2', attrs={"class":"venue-title", }) #scrape the elements
    cafeNames = [cafe.text.strip() for cafe in cafeNames] #clean the elements
    f = '{}'.format(''.join('({},)'.format(cafe) for cafe in cafeNames))
    tuple(f)

    print(f)

    sqlite_insert_with_param = """INSERT INTO testTable
                        (name)
                        VALUES
                        (?)"""


    cursor.executemany(sqlite_insert_with_param, f)

    sqliteConnection.commit()
    print("Python Variables inserted successfully into table ")

    cursor.close()

except sqlite3.Error as error:
    print("Failed to insert data into sqlite table", error)
finally:
    if (sqliteConnection):
        sqliteConnection.close()
        print("The SQLite connection is closed")
```

[image]

And here is the result in the table:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [cursor.execute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html?highlight=sqlite3#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) instead of `executemany`.

The later considers iterates over `f` and hence multiple inserts.

Here's an example using executemany using an array.

```py
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("create table testTable(name)")

names = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']
cur.executemany("insert into testTable(name) values (?)",  map(lambda name: (name, ), names))

for name in cur.execute('select name from testTable'):
    print(name)
```

Output

```
('name1',)
('name2',)
('name3',)
```

Comment: Thanks this solves the original problem! But now all names are inserting on one row of the table rather than one row per name...

Comment: You want to insert an array of names. In your code, try inserting `cafeNames` using `executemany`

Comment: Thanks for your response, when I try this I always get a  ``Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 5 supplied.`` Error

Comment: @deadant88 Updated post with an example. Hope it helps.